generating javadoc failed
I've been trying Javadoc for my project. made sure to have comments in English anywhere needed but it still not working. and just to note- I'm using UTF-8
basically all types of errors:

cannot find symbol import

error: package android.[...] does not exist

unmappable character (0x9D) for encoding windows-1252
* <li>Legacy language tags (marked as â€œType: grandfatheredâ€? in BCP 47) (in files I didn't create, and cannot edit)


"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\javadoc.exe" -locale en -public -splitindex -d C:\Users\micha\Desktop @C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\javadoc_args
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\ReDoPassword.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\Story.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\SignUp.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\DataBaseRecord.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\Utils\speechToTextHelper.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\Utils\Receiver.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\Utils\UserValidationHelper.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\Login.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\Utils\User.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\Utils\DatabaseHelper.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\Utils\DataPassListener.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\Utils\mainActivityHelper.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\test\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\ExampleUnitTest.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\RecyclerView\RV.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\RecyclerView\RV_adapter.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\MainActivity.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\Level.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\About.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\micha\Documents\Book_Buddy_after_javadoc_comment\Book_Buddy\app\src\main\java\com\example\bookbuddy\michal\book_buddy\activities\Profile.java...
Constructing Javadoc information...
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\pm\PackageManager.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
              ^
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: package android
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\app\AppOpsManager.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
              ^
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: package android
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\media\AudioAttributes.java:24: error: package android.audio.policy.configuration.V7_0 does not exist
import android.audio.policy.configuration.V7_0.AudioUsage;
                                              ^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\app\AppOpsManager.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsActiveCallback;
                               ^
  symbol:   class IAppOpsActiveCallback
  location: package com.android.internal.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\app\AppOpsManager.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsAsyncNotedCallback;
                               ^
  symbol:   class IAppOpsAsyncNotedCallback
  location: package com.android.internal.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\app\AppOpsManager.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsCallback;
                               ^
  symbol:   class IAppOpsCallback
  location: package com.android.internal.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\app\AppOpsManager.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsNotedCallback;
                               ^
  symbol:   class IAppOpsNotedCallback
  location: package com.android.internal.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\app\AppOpsManager.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService;
                               ^
  symbol:   class IAppOpsService
  location: package com.android.internal.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\app\AppOpsManager.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsStartedCallback;
                               ^
  symbol:   class IAppOpsStartedCallback
  location: package com.android.internal.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\pm\PackageInstaller.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
              ^
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: package android
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\pm\PackageInstaller.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
import android.content.IIntentReceiver;
                      ^
  symbol:   class IIntentReceiver
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\pm\PackageInstaller.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
import android.content.IIntentSender;
                      ^
  symbol:   class IIntentSender
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\icu\util\ULocale.java:87: error: unmappable character (0x9D) for encoding windows-1252
 * <li>Legacy language tags (marked as â€œType: grandfatheredâ€? in BCP 47)
                                                               ^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\icu\util\ULocale.java:3475: error: unmappable character (0x9D) for encoding windows-1252
     * supports legacy language tags (marked as â€œType: grandfatheredâ€? in BCP 47)
                                                                        ^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\telephony\TelephonyManager.java:4623: error: unmappable character (0x9D) for encoding windows-1252
     *        permanent identity with â€œ,â€?. Key identifier AVP is presented in ASCII string
                                            ^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\telephony\TelephonyManager.java:4624: error: unmappable character (0x9D) for encoding windows-1252
     *        with â€œname=valueâ€? format.
                                  ^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\os\Build.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
              ^
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: package android
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\os\Build.java:30: error: package android.sysprop does not exist
import android.sysprop.DeviceProperties;
                      ^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\os\Build.java:31: error: package android.sysprop does not exist
import android.sysprop.SocProperties;
                      ^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\os\Build.java:32: error: package android.sysprop does not exist
import android.sysprop.TelephonyProperties;
                      ^
C:\Users\micha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.8.0\d56176e5b2b55654d898039f3c3685cc9c221af7\activity-1.8.0-sources.jar(/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity.java):33: error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
              ^
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: package android
C:\Users\micha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.core\core\1.13.0\9ae580505557c829bed91310494b3ccd0a386dfd\core-1.13.0-sources.jar(/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.java):19: error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
              ^
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: package android
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\Context.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
import android.app.IApplicationThread;
                  ^
  symbol:   class IApplicationThread
  location: package android.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\Context.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
import android.app.IServiceConnection;
                  ^
  symbol:   class IServiceConnection
  location: package android.app
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\view\ViewGroup.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.internal.R;
                           ^
  symbol:   class R
  location: package com.android.internal
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.COLOR_MODE;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:19: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.COLOR_MODE;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.DENSITY_DPI;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:20: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.DENSITY_DPI;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.FONT_SCALE;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:21: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.FONT_SCALE;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.FONT_WEIGHT_ADJUSTMENT;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:22: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.FONT_WEIGHT_ADJUSTMENT;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.GRAMMATICAL_GENDER;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:23: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.GRAMMATICAL_GENDER;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.HARD_KEYBOARD_HIDDEN;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:24: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.HARD_KEYBOARD_HIDDEN;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.KEYBOARD;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:25: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.KEYBOARD;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.KEYBOARD_HIDDEN;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:26: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.KEYBOARD_HIDDEN;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.LOCALES;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:27: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.LOCALES;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.LOCALE_LIST;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:28: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.LOCALE_LIST;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.MCC;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:29: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.MCC;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.MNC;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:30: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.MNC;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.NAVIGATION;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:31: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.NAVIGATION;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.NAVIGATION_HIDDEN;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:32: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.NAVIGATION_HIDDEN;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.ORIENTATION;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:33: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.ORIENTATION;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SCREEN_HEIGHT_DP;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:34: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SCREEN_HEIGHT_DP;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SCREEN_LAYOUT;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:35: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SCREEN_LAYOUT;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SCREEN_WIDTH_DP;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:36: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SCREEN_WIDTH_DP;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SMALLEST_SCREEN_WIDTH_DP;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:37: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.SMALLEST_SCREEN_WIDTH_DP;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.TOUCHSCREEN;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationProto
  location: package android.content
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\content\res\Configuration.java:38: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.content.ConfigurationProto.TOUCHSCREEN;
^
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\view\InputDevice.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import android.Manifest;
              ^
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: package android
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\view\Window.java:19: error: package android.Manifest does not exist
import static android.Manifest.permission.HIDE_NON_SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOWS;


"javadoc" finished with exit code 1

i tried inserting in the command line arguments, a feild according sdk location, and it didnt help, and also editing the classes i didnt create, that been generated automaticly when creating a new project
i also thought about downloading some plygins to help me figure out how to continue, but didnt really understand what todo
